# Python - opencv - pyqt5

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5

When I try to import cv2 when using pyqt5 I have this error :

ImportError: /lib64/libQt5Widgets.so.5: symbol _ZN23QPlatformSystemTrayIcon16staticMetaObjectE, version Qt_5 not defined in file libQt5Gui.so.5 with link time reference

If I only import cv2 or pyqt5 there are no errors, but together it doesn't work.

What can i do to resolve my problem ?

```
import sys
import os
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import mainWindow

class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mainWindow = mainWindow.MainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = Application()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is your platform? How did you obtain cv2, pyqt5 packages? Note that OpenCV can also link in Qt5, you could have conflicting Qt versions in your build.

Comment: I use pyCharm on Linux (Fedora), i got cv2 by "yum install numpy opencv*" and pyqt by "dnf install PyQt5"